# Open iPhone or iPad to App Store Updates area

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store

I use a web service to check for app updates and notify my user an update is available.  Instead of taking them to the App Store product page as I do now, my users prefer I take them to the App Store Updates area so they can review the "what's new" and also update other apps at the same time.

Does anyone know how to get an iPhone/iPad app to open the App Store and navigate directly to the UPDATES area?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out using the item-apps url structure

Comment: Really? You couldn't just give the answer? That page doesn't contain any info on going to the Updates screen, as far as I can tell.

Comment: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes but I don't think this applies in some cases in iOS 6 now.  FYI